# Event on holding button

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

Is it possible to fire an event when the user is holding the back button for example ?

I'm able to do it for a touch hold on an element on the screen with touchstart/touchend events but for the back button, I have only this kind of event :

```
window.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(ev) {
    if (ev.keyName === 'back') {
        // hold logic here ?
    }
});
```

I know it's possible using the native API so can I do it with the web API ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I know, there is no web API to get the back (H/W) key hold-event in Tizen-Web.

---

Thanks !!!

Comment: Alright, I wanted to be sure before doing an other way.